# How to handle null data coming from a database in a combobox?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, binding, combobox

I've got a `ComboBox` on a window bound to data from a field in a table. This field is nullable. I bind a lookup table to the `ItemsSource` of the `ComboBox`. What I'm finding is that if the data from the data table has a null in the field, the combobox will show whatever is first in the `CollectionViewSource`that I bind to the `ItemsSource` (the lookup table). That isn't what I want. I've read that I should use the attribute of `TargetNullValue` to the `SelectedValue` of the `ComboBox`, but it always throws an error when I do that. Here's the XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbMajorProbByInterviewer"
      VerticalAlignment="Top"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource aSICodesSubstanceTypeViewSource2}}"
      DisplayMemberPath="SubstanceDesc"
      SelectedValue="{Binding MajorProblemByInterviewer, TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}}"
      SelectedValuePath="SubstanceType"
      Grid.Column="3" />
```

And the error that I get, every time I go to this window is: "Error getting data for ASICodesSubstanceType.  Input string was not in a correct format."

I've tried `TargetNullValue=''` and `TargetNullValue=' '` and `TargetNullValue='None'` and `TargetNullValue=`, but all of these throw that same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just what are you trying to do (achieve) with SelectedValue?

Comment: What is the type of `MajorProblemByInterviewer.SubstanceType`? Is it a String?

Comment: SubstanceType is a byte? (a nullable byte), but it isn't a part of MajorProblemByInterviewer. I'm sorry, but I didn't include that in this code.

What I was hoping would happen is if SubstanceType is null, that cmbMajorProbByInterviewer wouldn't have anything selected (SelectedIndex == -1).